# Python / Iterate over content of subprocess.check_output - line by line

Tags: python

I run the following in python:

```
list_m = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).strip('\n')
```

When I print, it gives me the following content:

```
Name     region     sort
b30      us         large
b40      europe     medium
```

I wish to iterate each line and print only the first word, so I will get for the first iteration `b30`, and for the second `b40`.

I try to loop over `list_m`:

```
for i in list_m
   print i
```

and it gives me the following:

```
N
a
m
e

r
e
```

and continue till medium.

How can I iterate the output each line, and print the first word?

Comment: `.split(' ')[0]` ?

Comment: You already can iterate over the lines. Now, just `split()` each line and print the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do your work

```
list(map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0], list_m.split('\n'))
```

Which is splitting you string line by line, then split by space and get first element.